# Attempting to develop server and client app concurrently with Webpack and Express

Tags: reactjs, express, webpack, jsx

**UPDATE***

I started a brand new project, updated all my dependencies. I have an injection occurring from the HTMLWebpackPlugin however nothing I can do makes webpack recognize JSX syntax?!?!?!?!?!

Here is the webpack.config

```
import webpack from 'webpack';
import path from 'path';
import HtmlWebpackPlugin from 'html-webpack-plugin';

export default {
  devtool: 'inline-source-map',
  entry: [
    'eventsource-polyfill', // necessary for hot reloading with IE
    'webpack-hot-middleware/client?reload=true', //note that it reloads the page if hot module reloading fails.
    path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/client/index')
  ],
  target: 'web',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
    publicPath: '/',
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin(),
    // Create HTML file that includes reference to bundled JS.
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: 'src/client/index.html',
      inject: true
    })
  ],
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {test: /\.js$/, exclude:  /(node_modules|bower_components)/, loader: 'babel-loader' },
      {test: /\.css$/, loaders: ['style-loader','css-loader']},
      {test: /\.eot(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: 'file-loader'},
      {test: /\.(woff|woff2)$/, loader: 'url-loader?prefix=font/&limit=5000'},
      {test: /\.ttf(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: 'url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=application/octet-stream'},
      {test: /\.svg(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: 'url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=image/svg+xml'}
    ]
  }
}
```

and here is my babelrc:

```
{
      "presets": [
        "react",
        "latest"
      ],
      "env": {
        "development": {
          "presets": [
            "react-hmre"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
```

I am at a loss. I just don't understand this at all. I receive a: `✖  26:7  Parsing error: Unexpected token <` error with every file with jsx syntax. They are all .js files.

I am trying to work on a demo react app and server together in the same project. I thought I understood how the process works but I clearly am lost as I cannot seem to get everything to work together with webpack and express.

I have my webpack config as:

```
import webpack from 'webpack';
import path from 'path';
import HtmlWebpackPlugin from 'html-webpack-plugin';

export default {
  debug: true,
  devtool: 'inline-source-map',
  noInfo: false,
  entry: [
    'eventsource-polyfill', // necessary for hot reloading with IE
    'webpack-hot-middleware/client?reload=true', //note that it reloads the page if hot module reloading fails.
    path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/client/index')
  ],
  target: 'web',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/client'),
        publicPath: '/',
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
  devServer: {
    contentBase: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/client')
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin(),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        filename: 'index.html',
        template: 'src/client/index.html',
        inject: true
    })
  ],
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {test: /\.js$/, include: path.join(__dirname, 'src/client'),exclude: '/node_modules/', loaders: ['babel']},
      {test: /(\.css)$/, loaders: ['style', 'css']},
      {test: /\.eot(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: 'file'},
      {test: /\.(woff|woff2)$/, loader: 'url?prefix=font/&limit=5000'},
      {test: /\.ttf(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: 'url?limit=10000&mimetype=application/octet-stream'},
      {test: /\.svg(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: 'url?limit=10000&mimetype=image/svg+xml'}
    ]
  }
};
```

However the htmlwebpack plugin is not injecting anything and when I add a script tag manually to '/bundle' I just get the html file again. I think it has something to do with trying to develop a server app too:

```
import express from 'express';
import open from 'open';

import configure from './configuration/server.configuration'; //eslint-disable-line import/default
import * as routes from '../common/api.routes';
import feedHandler from './routes/api.feeds.handler';
import socketHandler from './routes/socket.handler';

const app = express();

app.set('port', (process.env.PORT || 3000));

configure(app);
app.use(routes.BASE_API, feedHandler);

app.get('/', (req, resp)=>{
    resp.sendFile(app.get('index'));
});

const server = app.listen(app.get('port'), (err)=>{
    if(err){
        console.log(err); //eslint-disable-line no-console
    }else{
        open(`http://localhost:${app.get('port')}`);
    }
});

const io = socketHandler(server);
```

The configure app I had setup to differentiate between dev and server builds and is currently importing:

```
import webpack from 'webpack';
import path from 'path';
import config from '../../../webpack.config.dev';

export default function(app){
    const compiler = webpack(config);

    app.use(require('webpack-dev-middleware')(compiler, {
        noInfo: true,
        publicPath: config.output.publicPath
    }));

    app.use(require('webpack-hot-middleware')(compiler));
    app.set('index', path.join(__dirname, '../../client/index.html'));
    return app;
}
```

I am just completely lost here as express node development is out of my comfort zone as normally I just use MVC for server stuff. I have used webpack just for client react builds before and clearly I am not smart enough to try to do everything in a single build.

I have a repo setup for this here: [GitRepo](https://github.com/AndrewPHunter/react-socketio-example) and am currently working on the server-dev branch which is the one linked.

I am trying to figure out what I am doing wrong and why I cannot get anything working. Even my api routes just hang and don't return anything. I think perhaps it is because the webpack dev server is intercepting? I am not really sure and don't know even where to look for this in documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am going to mark this as closed. I wound up resetting the entire project to the excellent [React-Slingshot](https://github.com/coryhouse/react-slingshot) starter kit and then proceeding from there. JSX syntax is now being recognized and I think it was a weird dependency version problem.

I am unsure of what the issue was exactly and still working towards solid combined build system for both client and server development in the same repo. I plan on keep working on the git repo linked in the original post and will circle back when I have something I feel is sufficient.